# What type of data structure is this in Python?

Tags: python, structure

I ran across some code and I am not sure what this looks like. What are the numbers there for?

```
keyboard = (
            ("qwertyuiop", 0), ("QWERTYUIOP", 0), ("asdfghjkl", 1),
            ("ASDFGHJKL", 1), ("zxcvbnm,.", 2), ("ZXCVBNM<>", 2)
)
```

Comment: Might not be on-topic; question is about about specific implementation details of a program

Comment: The structure is a tuple of tuples. What the data represents should be asked to the author.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The numbers 0, 1, and 2 are not a required part of this data structure.

They are just values.

And a tuple can contain values of any type -- strings such as "qwertyuiop", numbers such as 0, etc.

Comment: This answer fails to identify what the data structure is: a tuple of tuples.

Since python is dynamically typed and there are no generics, it is also helpful to make inferences about the underlying abstract data type that this implements. i.e. It might be used to implement an ordered mapping from strings to integers.

Comment: @cosmicFluke Please expand your comment into a separate answer. Thanks!

Comment: I thought Luca's answer was sufficient. I downvoted this answer and it asked me to leave a comment as to why I downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), a grouping of values separated by commas. In this case, `keyboard` is a tuple of tuples.

The numbers probably represent some value related to the first value (text) of each tuple.

Comment: @Ishani If this answer has helped you or answered your question, please remember to mark it as the correct answer, so people can refer to it in the future :) Cheers!